# Excel 2016: Find Numbers That Are Missing From 5000 to 6000 in one column

Tags: excel, textjoin

I have a column (A) with numbers in order from 5000 to 6000. Now, some numbers are missing. For example number 5004 is missing from the column bellow.

1. `5000`
2. `5001`
3. `5002`
4. `5003`
5. `5005`
6. `5006`
7. `...`
8. `6000`

So, number `5004` is missing. How can I find all the numbers that are missing?

Comment: What excel are you using?  do you want the output in one cell or many?

Comment: hello, Scott. I am using Excel 2016. In one cell or many, whatever you want. Maybe both will be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it in many then put this in the first cell and copy/drag down:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("5000:6000"))/(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT("5000:6000")),A:A,0))),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

[image]

If you have Office 365 Excel and you want it in one cell then use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT("5000:6000")),A:A,0)),ROW(INDIRECT("5000:6000")),""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel and you still want it in one cell then you will need vba.

Put this UDF in a module attached to the workbook, and use the TEXTJOIN() formula described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: it is ok, WORKS SUPER ! The first solution is perfect, because I don't have Office 365 Excel. Thank you

Comment: @JustMe I realize that but just adding the other parts for those who come later.

Comment: by the way, Scott, can u please tell me how to count the numbers of cells containing a specific string / or a number, from a column, without scrolling down? in excel

Comment: got it `=COUNT(A1:A500)`